# insertTextAtCursor() function makes contenteditable lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a fix for this... Because this is very annoying, due to the fact that is happens every 1000 milliseconds!!!

Here's the full code:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function insertTextAtCursor() {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode( document.createTextNode('567') );
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
}
</script>


<div contenteditable onclick="insertTextAtCursor()">hi</div>


<script>
  setInterval(function() {
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/567/g,'<b>abcde-fghi</b>'));
  },1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Why does the div have a blank attribute `contenteditable` ?

Comment: I read that it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` to replace things like that. Scan the text nodes you care about and modify them.

Comment: @lucuma it makes the div editable. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the interval when the div has focus and then start it again on blur. I'd also change up the interval function by adding an id and replacing only those contents.  Also, I think a little cleaner way might be to do the interval and the replace data in a hidden element.

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/AKtvt/

```
function insertTextAtCursor() {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode( document.createTextNode('567') );
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
} 

function ReplaceData() {

    $("#contentdata").val($("#content").html().replace(/567/g,'<b>abcde-fghi</b>'));

    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ph=setInterval(ReplaceData,1000);


    $('#content').on("blur", function() {
       $('#content').html($('#contentdata').val());
        ph=setInterval(ReplaceData,1000);
    });

});
```

​
​

Comment: That doesn't work, because when it adds focus, it starts at the beginning of the contenteditable. If the user's caret is inside the div, and they're typing, that's a problem.

Comment: It is a div the user can't type inside it.  Your question doesn't make sense or is lacking some information.

Comment: The contenteditable attribute makes the div editable. That's how WYSIWYG editors work. All the modern browser's I've tested support it. If you test the code I provided, you'll see that the div is editable. What I want is so that the div does not loose focus every 1000 milliseconds.

Comment: @DumbSearch Sorry I just had a dumb moment I guess.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: No that's okay. :) Thanks for the answer, by the way. But I tested it out and it doesn't appear to work... :(

Comment: It still doesn't work. :( Please take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/drDL7/2/

Comment: I've tested it in chrome an FF.  When I click the div in the jsfiddle it adds the text at the place where I clicked.  You are on your own!

Comment: It does add text where clicked, but you doesn't replace that text onblur. I'm using FF 12.

Comment: Thanks! I've just marked your answer as "correct". And when I have enough reputation, I'll upvote. :-)